# Encrypt Gre tunnel traffic

Tags: gre

I have a gre tunnel between vyatta and juniper srx  . I would like to encrypt the gre tunnel traffic if its possible.

thanks 
Pratik

Comment: GRE, itself, is not encrypted. You can encrypt the data before it goes into the GRE tunnel, but GRE is just an encapsulation. There are other tunnel types that do encryption, but they may not have some GRE features you need, e.g. multicast-capable.

Comment: basically I am trying to established connectivity from juniper srx 240 to vyatta.  can I create ipsec tunnel on vyatta ?

Comment: [Here](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB19372) is example for Juniper SRX.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set up IPsec between the two devices. Then run GRE through the IPsec tunnel to allow multicast.

This may help.

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/configure-a-site-to-site-vpn-using-the-vyatta-network-appliance/